# How get non-followers using tweetsharp?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I use tweetsharp 2.3.1. to make simple twitter client. Do you know how get all non-followers (accounts that you follow, but they don't follow you). I know how do it with iteration, but what if account has thousands of followers? Are there standart functions to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: does twitter offer an API and if so have you consulted the documentation..?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard function in the Twitter REST API to get the information that you are looking for.

Call GET/Followers (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids) and GET/Friends (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids), and remove the Friends from the Followers.  The remaining items are the people you want.